# Slow JoinAcross performance

Tags: performance-tuning, bugs, associations, system-performance

**Bug introduced in 10.3**

---

I am using `JoinAcross` to combine two datasets, where the key is an Integer.

```
L = Get["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/557392/permalink/StackExchange/mathematica/107732/L.m"];
R = Get["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/557392/permalink/StackExchange/mathematica/107732/R.m"];

JoinAcross[L, R, "A", "Inner"]
```

The Dataset rendition of these associations is

For `L`:

[image: L Dataset]

For `R`:

[image: R Dataset]

Though this takes a couple of seconds in KNIME and/or GNU R, it takes an **hour or more** in *Mathematica* 10.3.1 on GNU/Linux.

What can I do to speed this operation up?

Comment: Ask Konstantin at WRI, he wrote that I believe.

Comment: 4.2 seconds, v10.1/Windows .  Similar on my linux box.

Comment: 3575.66 seconds, v10.3.1/Windows

Comment: 3.0 seconds v10.2/Mac.   I guess we've bracketed it to a change between 10.2 and 10.3.  Thanks everyone, I have contacted Wolfram Support.

Comment: This is a thousand-fold slowdown.  I think the bugs tag was warranted.