# How to subtract two lists based on a key

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, dataset

Let's say you have the following datasets `{set1, set2}`:

```
{set1, set2} = { { {"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3}, {"D", 4} }
               , { {"A", 111}, {"C", 333}, {"E", 555} }
               } //
  Query[All, Dataset, AssociationThread[{"ID", "Value"} -> #]&]
```

[image: {set1, set2} screenshot]

I would like to delete the differences in two datasets based on one column.
I was able to do so with the following:

```
JoinAcross[set1, DeleteCases[set1[All, "ID"], 
 Alternatives @@ set2[All, "ID"]][All, <|"ID" -> #|> &], "ID"]
```

[image: JoinAcross dataset screenshot]

However, I believe there has to be a more efficient method.

Comment: "delete the differences based on one column": I don't understand this. Can you add a sample dataset and the desired output?

Comment: @MarcoB I moved the sample datasets from my response into the question.

Comment: @WReach Thank you!

Comment: You can use the SQL/SQLite inside the MMA. This is the fastest way - just send your table there and run the corresponding SELECT query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Complement` to find the elements in `set1` whose *ID* values are not contained within `set2`:

```
Complement[set1, set2, SameTest -> (#["ID"] === #2["ID"] &)]
```

[image: Complement dataset screenshot]

---

**Update for the revised question**

`Complement` provides a nice notational convenience, but for large (15,000) sets it runs orders of magnitude slower than the solution proposed in the question.  The problem is that `Complement` is optimized to be very fast when it uses the standard `SameTest` but that performance degrades sharply when a user-supplied test is used.

We can get a bit of notational improvement while retaining performance by combining the two solutions:

```
JoinAcross[Complement[set1[All, {"ID"}], set2[All, {"ID"}]], set1, "ID"]
```

[image: JoinAcross/Complement dataset screenshot]

Here we use the standard "high-speed" version of `Complement` to operate upon the *ID* fields projected out of the original sets.  We then generate the result by joining the complemented keys to the original set.

The original solution could also be simplified a little yet remain performant by incorporating the projection strategy alone, sticking with `DeleteCases` over `Complement`:

```
JoinAcross[
  DeleteCases[set1[All, {"ID"}], Alternatives @@ set2[All, {"ID"}]]
, set1, "ID" ]
```

[image: JoinAcross/DeleteCases dataset screenshot]

*Datasets Are Slightly Slower*

None of these solutions is faster than the original.  It is hard to beat the highly-optimized `Cases`/`Alternatives` combination (though I look forward to someone posting something faster).  However, we can gain around a 10% performance improvement on all of these solutions if we operate upon the raw lists of associations rather than objects wrapped in `Dataset`.  `Dataset` introduces some minor overheads.  Normally, I would not abandon a notational convenience in return for a 10% performance improvement, but the option is there if desired.

*Imperative Solution*

An imperative solution offers the same fast performance again:

```
Module[{keep}
, keep[_] = True
; Scan[(keep[#ID] = False)&, set2]
; set1[Select[keep[#ID]&]]
]
```

Even though it is no faster than the other solutions, it retains its speed while offering flexibility should the retention criteria go beyond simple key equality.

**Performance Disclaimer**

All claims of performance in this response are current as of version 12.0.0.  Many WL functions have shown wild swings in performance between releases, even by orders of magnitude (both up and down).  `JoinAcross` is [one such function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107732/142).  Element access with `Association` and `Dataset` have also shown swings, although not as dramatic as `JoinAcross`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, using your complement method on larger datasets with 15,000 occurrences each, it is over 100 times slower than my original one. I have no idea what is the cause, any thoughts on an improvement?

Comment: It is disappointing, but not entirely surprising, that the purpose-built function is slower than a user-written function.  Now that the focus of the question has shifted from notation to efficiency, I'll withdraw my answer until I can spend time to think of something else.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's do it with datasets having unnamed columns, because they are simpler.  We use `Intersection` to find common elements in the first column.  We use a simple replacement rule that replaces a list, which represents a row in the dataset, with `Nothing`.

```
{nest1, nest2} = {{{"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3}, {"D", 4}}, 
     {{"A", 111}, {"C", 333}, {"E", 555}}};

{set1, set2} = Dataset /@ {nest1, nest2}

x = Intersection[set1[[All, 1]], set2[[All, 1]]];

set1 = set1 /. ({#, _} -> Nothing &  /@ x);
set2 = set2 /. ({#, _} -> Nothing &  /@ x);

{set1, set2}
```

[image]

[image]

Now do it using datasets with named columns.  We use the same syntax for the `Intersection`, but now the rows of the datasets are represented with associations instead of lists, so the replacement rule is a little different.

```
{set1, set2} = {{{"A", 1}, {"B", 2}, {"C", 3}, {"D", 4}}, {{"A", 
     111}, {"C", 333}, {"E", 555}}} // 
  Query[All, Dataset, AssociationThread[{"ID", "Value"} -> #] &]

With[{x = Intersection[set1[[All, 1]], set2[[All, 1]]]},
 set1 = set1 /. (<|"ID" -> #, _|> -> Nothing &  /@ x);
 set2 = set2 /. (<|"ID" -> #, _|> -> Nothing &  /@ x);
 ]
{set1, set2}
```

Same output as before.

**Speed Comparison**

The results of `RepeatedTiming` indicate the intersection/replacement method can be 3 times faster than `JoinAcross` for datasets with named columns in MMA 12.0.0.  In the comparison test the first set has 20000 rows, the second set has 1500 rows and the number of rows in common is 300.  Here's how the test sets are generated:

```
nrows1 = 20000; nrows2 = 1500; ncomm = 300;
nest1 = Transpose[{
    StringJoin /@ 
     RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {nrows1, 8}],
    RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, nrows1]}];
nest2 = RandomSample@Join[
    Transpose[{
      StringJoin /@ 
       RandomChoice[CharacterRange["A", "Z"], {nrows2 - ncomm, 6}],
      RandomInteger[{1, 1000}, nrows2 - ncomm]}],
    RandomChoice[nest1, ncomm]];

{set1, set2} = {nest1, nest2} // 
   Query[All, Dataset, AssociationThread[{"ID", "Value"} -> #] &];
```

Check the `RepeatedTiming` results for the `JoinAcross` method

```
JoinAcross[set1, 
   DeleteCases[set1[All, "ID"], Alternatives @@ set2[All, "ID"]][
    All, <|"ID" -> #|> &], "ID"] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.15  *)
```

Check the `RepeatedTiming` results for the intersection / replacement method

```
With[{x = Intersection[set1[[All, 1]], set2[[All, 1]]]},
   With[{rule = <|"ID" -> #, _|> -> Nothing &  /@ x},
    set1 = set1 /. rule;
    ]] // RepeatedTiming // First
(*  0.03749  *)
```

Similar results were obtained with datasets having 200000 rows and with smaller datasets.